# Are these Passive clause sentences?

Tags: passive-voice

1.Nobody is following what being said.(somebody is saying something and at the same time nobody is following him/her).

2.Nobody is following what being said.(something was said earlier but now nobody is following).

Now if we don't use auxiliary 'is' in first sentence and 'was' in second sentence. They are the same.
My question is we can use 'being+PP' without 'is' or 'are' as auxiliaries in first sentence but we have to use 'were' auxiliary in second sentence to show that something was said before

Comment: You can't use `was` in either. The second sentence would need to be qualified with something like `any more` i.e `Nobody is following what is being said any more`. If you wanted to use `was`, it would be `Nobody was listening to what was being said`, which makes it all in the past.

Comment: Please check your examples.  The second one doesn't have the word "was".  And do you mean "is being said" in the first?

Comment: For second sentence it means like this: something was said(means instructions) by authorities all day yesterday on how public should behave for today's event but public not following those instructions. Now can I say the second sentence? 2.Nobody is following what being said.(something was said earlier but now nobody is following). Also without 'were'?